# Android OpenGL get the rendering result as a Java Byte array

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have 2 [`OES_EGL_image_external`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt) textures that I combine (sampling from both) and render to an input `Surface` given by the `MediaCodec`, and later encode and save to a mp4 file.

What I want to do instead is get the combined frame as a Java Byte array.
I read that rendering it to a texture and using `glReadPixels()` is really slow, and I have to keep up with about 30-40 FPS.

What would be the most efficient way to do it in Android?

Comment: `glReadPixels (...)` isn't so much slow if you use it correctly as it is late. Sustaining a certain frame rate is much easier when you can tolerate waiting 2-3 frames for the result to become available in a Pixel Buffer Object. What version of OpenGL ES are you working with (your question is tagged wrong, by the way)? In 3.0+ Pixel Buffer Objects are core, otherwise you may only be able to do this if [`GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/NV/NV_pixel_buffer_object.txt) is available.

Comment: Opengl es 2. I'm not familiar with pixel buffer objects. Do you mind providing an example or a bit more details please?  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate question! The subject is nor trivial!

Comment: I hate to speak on genpfault's behalf, but usually if you see a question with "edited x hours ago" with genpfault's name, it also coincides with a -1 vote. As for your situation, I do not think you have access to pixel buffer objects and I do not know the efficient way to do this in ES 2.0.

Comment: @genpfault, how is your downvote and edit of my "Thank you" helpful? I'm asking a legitimate question. If you can't help that's fine, but by downvoting it you're preventing other people from seeing it and helping.

Comment: Looks like I shouldn't work the [tag:opengl] "active" queue before morning coffee, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "fast" path, but the "slow" path isn't all that slow.

The only way to get the contents of an "external" texture is to render it somewhere (say, a pbuffer) and then read the pixels out.  This is because external textures can be in a "foreign" color format (usually some flavor of YUV), so the set of supported operations is limited.  It sounds like you want the output of a GLES operation that merges two frames, though, so this isn't an issue.

You are unlikely to have [PBOs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) in GLES 2 on Android, and even if you did you'd probably need to use the NDK as I don't think Java-language bindings exist.  (Speaking as of 'K' and probably 'L', don't know what's coming in 'M'.)

As far as reading pixels out goes, my experiments with the [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest) found that it took `glReadPixels()` about 8ms to pull a 720p frame out, which is fast enough for your purposes.  The speed will vary significantly from device to device and release to release (and possibly color format -- for example, some code I was running specified RGB rather than RGBA, and got sent down a slow path).  There is a rudimentary benchmark in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) that can be used to get a general sense.

The output of `glReadPixels()` goes to a "direct" ByteBuffer, which is not guaranteed to be backed by a `byte[]`.  In recent versions of Android (since maybe Jellybean?) it is guaranteed for buffers allocated with `allocDirect()`, but might not work for buffers created with the JNI functions.  So be careful with your chosen allocation method.

All that being said... once you have your data in a `byte[]`, there isn't a whole lot you can do with it from Java that will retain your desired frame rate, unless your images are fairly small.  You would be much better off finding a way to solve your problem with the GPU.